# Delay in source block with specific arrivals

Tags: java, anylogic

I'm making a model that simulates the entry of ships into a canal.

I have two source blocks with entries defined by arrival tables. I created a source block based on the database that contains all the data from my scenario, I indicated the arrivals through the database (arrival date) and in Agent Parameters mapping I defined the parameters and related columns. The second source block is defined in the same way, however, from another database.

I want to implement a solution to define that if an agent from the second source block (ships_terc) is created on the same day as an agent from the first (ships_ac), there is a change in the other arrival dates from the first source (ship_ac).

For example, if an agent on ship_terc has an arrival date equal to that of ship_ac, all next agents must be generated on original_arrivaldata + 3 hours.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Add more specific questions.The information is insufficient and is not at all close to minimum reproducible problem

Comment: You will need to code this up, there is no build-in setup in AnyLogic to help with such a specific requirement. Start learning Java by doing the step-by-step tutorials first and try to take it from there. Else, do this in the input data instead, if you are more comfortable with Excel or whatever the data is from